How to update a form using Flask,jinja?
Model
class ContentOwner(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String,primary_key=True, default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()))
    owner = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    reference_code = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    target_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('target.id'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

Form
class AddContentOwnerForm(FlaskForm):
    owner = StringField('Owner name')
    reference_code = StringField('reference code')

<div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ gettext('Content Owners')}}<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success float-end" href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addContentOwnermodal">Add</button></div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Ref Code</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          {% for owner in owners %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{owner.owner}}</td>
                            <td>{{owner.reference_code}}</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm float-end" href="{{ url_for('editOwner', id=owner.id) }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editOwnerModal">Edit</button></td>
                            <td> <a href="{{url_for('deleteOwner', id=owner.id)}}" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-end">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %} 
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

edit_owner_modal.html

<div class="modal fade" id="editOwnermodal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editOwnermodalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editOwnerModalLabel">{{ gettext('Edit Owner')}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method='POST' action="{{url_for('editOwner', id=owner.id)}}">
                    {{ AddContentOwnerForm.csrf_token }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="editOwner">
                    
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text">{{ gettext('Name')}}</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="owner" value="{{owner.owner}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text">{{ gettext('Reference Code')}}</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reference_code" value="{{owner.reference_code}}">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="d-grid col-12 mx-auto">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">{{ gettext('Update')}}</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">{{ gettext('Close')}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



routes.py
@app.route('/editowner/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def editOwner(id):
    owner = ContentOwner.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        owner.owner = request.form['owner']
        owner.reference_code = request.form['reference_code']
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('administration'))
    return render_template('edit_owner_modal.html', owner=owner, id=id)

@app.route('/administration', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def administration():
    addcontentownerform = AddContentOwnerForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':  
        if request.form['type'] == 'addContentOwner':
            if addcontentownerform.validate_on_submit():
                content_owner = ContentOwner(owner=addcontentownerform.owner.data, 
                                 reference_code=addcontentownerform.reference_code.data)
                db.session.add(content_owner)
                db.session.commit()
                flash(f"Added Owner '{addcontentownerform.owner.data}'", "alert-success")
                return redirect(url_for('administration'))
         elif request.form['type'] == 'editOwner': 
            if addcontentownerform.validate_on_submit():
                id = request.form.get('id')
                owner = ContentOwner.query.get_or_404(id)
                owner.owner = request.form['owner']
                owner.reference_code = request.form['reference_code']
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Owner details updated successfully.', 'success')
                return render_template('administration.html', id=id)
                    
       
    owners = db.session.query(ContentOwner).all()
    owner = db.session.query(ContentOwner).all()
    return render_template('administration.html',AddCrawlerForm=addcrawlerform, EditContentOwnerForm=editcontentownerform, AddUserForm=adduserform, AddJobForm=addjobform, AddContentOwnerForm=addcontentownerform, crawlers=crawlers, users=users, jobs=jobs, owners=owners, owner=owner)

when I click on the edit button, the form is not already filled to update and also on clicking update it raises 404 error. HELP!!!
I think the form(modal) is not getting the owner id details. Not sure if the administration page has error in accessing the route(editOwner)

Embedding a form of this type in a modal is not optimal, especially since I think you want to assign multiple entries on a single modal. It is more advisable to distribute the task over several pages.
Nevertheless, it is possible to develop a workable solution.
The following minimal example loads the content of the modal using AJAX depending on the owner's id. If the form is to be displayed, an attribute with the id is extracted from the respective button and a GET request is sent to the route for editing. The response from the server is the filled form, which is added to the modal. If the form is now sent via POST request, depending on whether the entries are valid, the database can be updated or error messages can be displayed.
Flask (./app.py)
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    flash, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    url_for
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='your secret here', 
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///example.db'
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class ContentOwner(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String,primary_key=True, default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()))
    owner = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    reference_code = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    # ...

class AddContentOwnerForm(FlaskForm):
    owner = StringField('Name')
    reference_code = StringField('Ref Code')

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    content_owner = ContentOwner(
        owner='Unknown', 
        reference_code='12345678'
    )
    db.session.add(content_owner)
    content_owner = ContentOwner(
        owner='Unknown 1', 
        reference_code='abcdefgh'
    )
    db.session.add(content_owner)
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/edit-owner/<uuid:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_owner(id):
    owner = ContentOwner.query.get_or_404(str(id))
    form = AddContentOwnerForm(request.form, obj=owner)
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        if form.validate():
            form.populate_obj(owner)
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            for k,v in form.errors.items(): 
                for error in v:
                    flash(f'{k}: {error}', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('administration'))
    return render_template('edit_owner_modal.html', **locals())

@app.route('/administration')
def administration():
    owners = ContentOwner.query.all()
    return render_template('administration.html', **locals())

HTML (./templates/administration.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Administration</title>
    <link 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></head>
<body>
    <main class="container mt-4">

        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for category, message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ (category,'primary')[category == 'message'] }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                  {{ message }}
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Ref Code</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for owner in owners -%}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{owner.owner}}</td>
                    <td>{{owner.reference_code}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button 
                            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm float-end" 
                            data-id="{{ owner.id }}" 
                            data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                            data-bs-target="#editOwnerModal">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor -%} 
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </main>

    <div class="modal fade" id="editOwnerModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editOwnerModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="editOwnerModalLabel">Edit Owner</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-body"></div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script 
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        (function() {
            const myModalEl = document.getElementById('editOwnerModal');
            myModalEl.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
                const relatedTarget = event.relatedTarget;
                const id = relatedTarget.dataset.id; 
                const modalBody = document.querySelector('#editOwnerModal .modal-body');
                modalBody.innerHTML = '<p style="text-align: center;">... Loading data ...</p>';
                fetch(`/edit-owner/${id}`)
                    .then(resp => resp.ok && resp.text())
                    .then(text => text && (modalBody.innerHTML = text));
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>

HTML (./templates/edit_owner_modal.html)
<form method='POST' action="{{url_for('edit_owner', id=owner.id)}}">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        {{ form.owner.label(class_='input-group-text') }}
        {{ form.owner(class_='form-control') }}
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        {{ form.reference_code.label(class_='input-group-text') }}
        {{ form.reference_code(class_='form-control') }}
    </div>
    <div class="d-grid col-12 mx-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>

